# Can one make Eclipse's "JPA Details" view's Query textbox bigger?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, jpql, dali

It took me forever to figure out how to get JPQL auto-completing to working in eclipse.
The only place I can see that happening is to add a <mapping-file>
to my persistance.xml and in the mapping .xml file I can define a <named-query> . Then if I add the "JPA Details" view and I select the query I want to edit, I get a tiny 4-line textbox 
in which I must edit my query. Only in this tiny textbox do I get content assistance.

A) Is there any way to hack this textbox to be bigger?
(My queries are quite complicated and I need a lot more lines)

B) Is there any other bigger place to get JPQL content assist?

(I have the same issue in Indigo 3.7 and Juno 4.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content assistant is also available via @NamedQuery annotation. If it makes no difference for you to store configuration in XML file or using annotations over Entity class, then you can take advantage of the latter. As soon as you begin editing 'query' element of a @NamedQuery, the same content assistant is available as in JPA Details / Queries. It gives you plenty of space; however, since it's a String constant defined in Java code, you'll have to deal with extra quotes and concatenation in case of query split into multiple lines. At the same time, you will be able to review this query in JPA Details view.

As for JPA Details view, I doubt if this Query editbox is configurable, unless modifying plug-in sources and rebuilding.

**EDIT** In response to comment (3),- here's a 'direction':

- JPA Details view along with panels/panes defined in org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui plug-in
- Named Query edit views are defined in classes `NamedQueryPropertyComposite` and `NamedQueryProperty2_0Composite` for JPA v1 and JPA v2 accordingly.
- the code fragment that adjusts named query editor box to 4 lines, looks as following:

  ```
  adjustMultiLineTextLayout(
      4,
      provider.getStyledText(),
      provider.getStyledText().getLineHeight()
  );
  ```

.. where 4 is line count.

The sources are found here: :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/webtools (not sure which specific Eclipse version they are targeted on, but this is definitely newer than what comes with Indigo).

Comment: 1) Eclipse insists to keep my named queries in one line 2) I'm putting it in the xml file to avoid all them quotes 3)Yes I figured i'll need to modify the sources, maybe someone can point me in the right direction. 4)After all that effort, I realized that my queries are in any case so complex that the eclipse plugin can't understand them (Hibernate runs them fine but the IDE says there is errors).

Comment: Indeed, when query split into multiple lines, Eclipse seems to be unable to parse the query any more.

Comment: @AmanicA: Let me know how did it go..  With matching versions it should be as simple as checking out just this single plug-in (which would use your Eclipse as a target platform). The path to this plug-in in CVS is /org.eclipse.jpa/components/jpa/plugins/org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui

Answer (score 2):

I have entered a bug against the Dali Eclipse project to make this text area larger and have it expand. No hack needed once that is fixed.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386416

In response to comment (4) - Please enter bugs against Dali for the specific validation errors you are seeing with your complex queries. We definitely want to fix those if they are spec-compliant JPQL queries. If they include anything hibernate specific, the hibernate tools extension would be responsible for that validation.

Comment: I think it should be configurable so that developer could change it according to his or her average queries. Added it as an issue comment.

Comment: Karen it is spec compliant as far as I can tell, I think my issues were with nested queries eg. SELECT NEW pkg.TableMetadata(table_oir
, (SELECT pi.value FROM table_oir.propertyInstances pi
    WHERE pi.property.name = 'x')
, description_pi.value
) FROM ObjectInstanceRevision table_oir,
IN (table_oir.propertyInstances) description_pi
WHERE table_oir.objectInstance.objectClass.objectClassId
= 'y'

Comment: Karen I discovered a neat maven/jpa trick which does understandably make Dali cry: I use maven properties (from pom.xml) in my mapping file which get preprocessed by maven. In that way I remove a lot of cruft from my queries eg. SELECT NEW ${lsods-source}TableMetadata((SELECT pi.value FROM table_oir.propertyInstances pi
    WHERE pi.property.name = ${LsodsMetadata}TABLE_NAME)
) FROM ObjectInstanceRevision table_oir
WHERE table_oir.objectInstance.objectClass.objectClassId
= ${LsodsMetadata}OBJECT_CLASS_ID__TABLE

Comment: Cool trick, but I don't imagine will be adding support for those maven properties since we don't have a maven processing engine :). You can turn off the Dali JPQL query validation if you'd like (under preferences->JPA->Errors/Warnings-> Queries and Generators -> 'Invalid or Incomplete JPQL queries' can be set to ignore). Then you don't have to remove the JPA facet and can still get other Dali code assist, validation, UI, etc

Comment: @AmanicA You may have hit a bug in the jpql parser that has been fixed. I created an object model that I think matches your complex nested query example and I do not have a validation error in Juno. I have not yet found the corresponding bug so I am unsure where it was fixed.

Comment: @KarenButzke Yes I made the errors go away like that, thanks. I don't think you need a maven engine to support this though, but you would need to use the processed files for validation. I think Eclipse is supporting this somehow because they are picked up when running maven apps from eclipse. But I can understand if this is a low priority :)